# Get current page number in ng-tables

Tags: ngtable

How to get current page number the user is seeing? And when the table is refreshed it can land him on the same page instead of specifying 1st page always.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the current page number use: `this.tableParams.page()`
To set the page number use: `this.tableParams.page(3)`

You will need to change 'tableParams' with whatever your table object is called. 
Also be mindful that if your data is dynamic and you set the page to something out of the max page range then the data will just not show.

Comment: Thanks a lot Man !